# AWS WebSocket API return forbidden (403) error when sending message

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Created AWS API Gateway WebSocket and try to send message from React APP.
It throw an error when try to send messages. I checked all the routes are correct and there is not any authentication configured.

But stil it throw forbdding errors. I can connect to the websocket.

I am expecting to send messages and it should receive by a lambda function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending the valid payload. The message should be in a json format.
More info: https://youtu.be/EZrXBnca4KY